# Использование вложенных URL вызывает /index/ в ссылке

Tags: .htaccess, url, modx, redirect, revo

В MODx Revo при включении опции "Использовать вложенные URL" (при настройке Дружелюбных URL), появляется /index/ в ссылке. Например:

```
site.ru/index/catalog/product
```

А при выключении вложенных урлов исчезает структура ссылок. Каждая страница открывается от корня сайта, не зависимо от того, в каком она разделе находится, например:

```
site.ru/catalog
site.ru/product
```

Как это исправить? .htaccess использовал как только мог, во всю силу своих знаний. Ничего не помогает.

Привожу свой .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# +/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]

# -index.html
RewriteRule ^index\.html / [R=301,L]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

php_flag register_globals Off

# -www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# -index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Думаю, что появление `/index/` в url ни как не связано с .htaccess.

Comment: Проблема решена. Приведу решение, которое предложил Павел Романов (modx.ru): 1. Переместите ресурс «Меню-1» в корень.
2. Заморозьте у него URI (на вкладке «Настройки» отметьте соответствующий чекбокс и просто пропишите URI без /index/).
3. Можно использовать приложение CustomUrls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решением было бы сделать главную страницу сайта на одном уровне с основными разделами (ресурасми), и не было бы нужды городить огород с перемещением разделов и заморозкой урлов, и не было бы сложностей с этим огородом в будущем.